# calligraphy brush

Tags: adobe-illustrator, brush, calligraphy, pencil

after writing a hand written letter with calligraphy brush when i want to add some details with pencil tool it does not add the detail on same brush and it automatically turns into basic brush instead of 30pt flat. what could be the reason? I am using a tablet.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make certain `New Art Has Basic Appearance` is **not** checked in the **Appearance Panel Menu**...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the Pencil tool with a brush initially. There's a bit of glitch in recent versions of Illustrator so that when you switch to the Pencil Tool, the brush is still indicated in the tool options, and you can even select a brush, but when you draw with it, it will return to a basic setting.

The pencil tool is ordinarily used for basic paths despite what the tool options might be showing. You can apply a brush after you've drawn it though. Also Scott's suggestion will work.

Comment: Does the Pencil reset with each use, in spite of the `New Art Has Basic Appearance` (NAHBA) setting? I don't have a "bleeding edge" version so I can't really test. Here, the Pencil **always** draws a basic path initially. But, you can apply a brush *after* the first path is drawn, *then* that brush will remain set for the Pencil Tool if the NAHBA option is not ticked.

Comment: @Scott Yes. The problem is that when you switch to the Pencil the tool it still shows the Calligraphy brush selected, but when you draw with it, it then reverts back to "basic". It's quite annoying. I'm on CC 2018. I assume they still haven't fixed it.  You can still apply a brush afterwards, just as in older versions.

Comment: +1 Good to know. Thanks! I'm still using CS6 and CC2017 for the most part - and it's fine in both of those - sounds like they broke it in 2018

Comment: @Scott - it can confuse the hell out of beginners!  First time I saw it was a WTF moment.

Comment: @Scott - sorry, i dind't mean to say your technique doesn't work, it does, but the initial setting will show a brush, but as soon as you draw it will change back to basic. This is what causes the confusion. Just a little glitch in the user interface I think.  It's not broken.

Comment: No problem Billy `:)` There's no accounting for odd random visual bugs. No worries.

Comment: thank you for your response. I was following a lesson on udemy and i was quite confused that it did not work same as the instructor's video. After @Scott comment, i realized it was checkhed on mine and when i fixed it problem got solved.